# Applying for a job, could I get advice on the additional questions?

Tags: applications

This is a good tip I got, it's an apprenticeship in admin at a special needs school. Apparently they recently advertised the job and had no suitable applicants, so they have put it up again, just a couple of hours ago.

This may seem like common sense, but I want to make the right impression and secure an interview.

> Please describe why Safeguarding will be an essential part of this job role

and

> Please describe your understanding of Data Protection.

I'll appreciate any advice. I've never worked before and have been trying to get my foot in the door for a long time.

Comment: Post these questions separately on either http://serverfault.com/ or the security site. Include your own definition and ask for clarification. You don't want to sound like you want someone else to do your homework.

Comment: @JeffO i'm not sure SF would be good...simply because the current culture around there is quite terrible.  I was considering flagging this question for possible migration...but the prevailing attitudes of SF (professionals ONLY, everyone else can get lost) probably wouldn't help much.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on the assumption (on the basis of the wording of the questions) that this is a school in the UK - if not, then the answer is probably off-target.

**Safeguarding**: I expect that Safeguarding refers to the definition in (for example) the Department for Education's "Safeguarding Children and Safer Recruitment in Education" (https://www.education.gov.uk/publications/standard/publicationdetail/page1/DFES-04217-2006)

> Safeguarding and promoting the welfare of children is defined for the
>   purposes of this guidance as:
>
> - protecting children from maltreatment;
> - preventing impairment of children’s health or development;
> - ensuring that children are growing up in circumstances consistent with the provision of safe and effective care; and
> - undertaking that role so as to enable those children to have optimum life
>     chances and to enter adulthood successfully.

Section 2.1 explains that a requirement for safeguarding from the Education Act 2002, and section 2.6 explains some aspects which are relevant.  Safeguarding is relevant for anyone working in education - how it applies would be specific to the role.

**Data Protection**: I expect that this is a reference to the Data Protection Act 1998, for which the Information Commissioner's Office provides guidance on their web site. This relates to collecting, processing, handling, and protecting personal data (i.e. data about individuals).

There is guidance for the education sector at http://www.ico.org.uk/for_organisations/sector_guides/education, including their report "Helping schools meet their data protection obligations - in plain English" which includes particular areas that schools need to consider.

Comment: +1 This is very good answer in that it *first* tries to define the vague terms in the original questions (especially the first one). First define, then elaborate or give opinions.

Answer (score 0):

While this is lengthy, it does cover a few points to ponder that I hope are useful.  Take some time to look up each of the capitalized terms and consider how you'd apply the concept that is being discussed as I suspect these questions are intended to be tests of communication skills as well as if you know these terms.

Is Safeguarding a company, an application, or merely a process for protecting something?  There are a few ways to interpret the term and this is worth doing some digging just to see if it is what you think or don't think as some terms could be company names like Oracle while others may be referring to the use of something like Incident Reporting.

As this is for an apprenticeship, it is worth considering that some background information may be expected.  For example, restoring from a backup may be part of Data Protection for some people.  IT Security could be an alternative part of Data Protection from a rather high level for another way to view this.

Last but not least, be careful with your language as things like spelling and grammar may count a great deal.  If you have an application with a bunch of typos that may come across as unprofessional.  Similarly, if you take a specific interpretation of a term that isn't what they were expecting that could also set a bad impression as you have to remember that context can be quite important.

For example, consider the case if they asked, "Please describe your understanding of Diamond."  Now, how many different kinds of Diamond do you know?  I know of at least a few:

1. Gem - This would be the jewelry where there are diamonds in earrings, necklaces and rings to give a few examples.  A rather hard substance and sometimes used in mining and lasers.
2. Card suit - The red pointed suit in a standard deck of playing cards.  The second lowest suit in order in Bridge for a more specific reference to this case.
3. Baseball structure - In the game of baseball, part of the field is known as a diamond consisting of 3 bases and home plate.
4. Singer - Neil Diamond would be a rather famous singer known for various songs that may be another point of where the term could be reference.
5. Security - The DJIA ETF trades under the ticker "DIA" and is sometimes called a diamond.
6. Song - There is a Rhianna song called "Diamonds" that could also be another case here.

This is without getting into metaphors where the term could be used that would complicate this further.  Thus, it is worth knowing which kind of admin is this: Clerical work maintaining files and paperwork or is it IT systems organizing and security work.  I could imagine an "Admin Assistant" being like a secretary or office manager and I could imagine an "Systems Admin" being like the gatekeeper that provides access to electronic systems.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Since it is a job at a special needs school, I imagine this is the relevant meaning of 'safeguarding'? http://www.safenetwork.org.uk/getting_started/Pages/Why_does_safeguarding_matter.aspx

Comment: Yes, that would be my guess too.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that for a computer/system/network admin, they are talking specifically about IT Security meanings of these words.  As a commenter mentioned - ITSecurity.stackexchange.com is a great place to go to define these words.

But what you really need to do with these answers is connect the term as it is used in your field to the nature of the business and the problems they need to solve.  Since both terms come from security - what would they be trying to protect and how can these concepts provide protection?

Realize, as well, that in a small business with only a few technical people, you may very well be talking to someone who read the jargon but who doesn't know the meaning, so translation will be a part of your job and your ability to talk it over with your employer will be a key to being successful in the role.  Figure that this isn't the only time you'll have to answer a question like this... and also if they are asking this sort of question, they may have a need for an overall security minded person.